# Hide fixed header on scroll down, show on scroll up and hover version 2 please

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

I know that this question has been asked here before, but i don't really like the way it is scripted and looks unstable when running.

I would like the following:

- Hide header on scroll down with a fadeout
- Show header on scroll up with a fadein
- Show header on hover

I decided not to show some of the js from the other examples, because people intend to work on those, but they don't work that good.

Hope someone can help must be easy for a coder.

[--> FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/q2dxojss/)

Html:

```
<header>
<nav>
    <div class="mob-nav">
        <div class="nav-toggle"><i class="nav-icon"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="left-nav">   
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Pixelation</a></li>    
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-nav">  
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `scroll` function in jQuery like this -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var iScrollPos = 0;
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     var iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos) {
         $('header').fadeOut(500);
     } else {
        $('header').fadeIn(500);
     }
     iScrollPos = iCurScrollPos;
 });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* width and height value includes content, padding and border not the margin */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* remove highlight on touch devices */
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%; /* sticky footer  */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 2500px;
}

body {
  font-family:  "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #000;
}

body, input, textarea, select, button {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.mob-nav {
  display: none; /* hide mobile nav */
}

nav ul.left-nav {
  float: left;
}

nav ul.right-nav {
  float: right;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0; /* remove default spacing */
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 44px;
}

nav a:link, 
nav a:visited {
  color: #111;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <nav>
  <div class="mob-nav">
   <div class="nav-toggle"><i class="nav-icon"></i></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="left-nav"> 
   <li class="home"><a href="#">Pixelation</a></li> 
  </ul>
  <ul class="right-nav"> 
   <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Is it possible to add a show on hover in that script? And add extra scrollup before that it shows the header, because it is now directly on the scrollup it looks a bit nervous adding some extra scroll up will solve that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
 (function () {
      var previousScroll = 0;

   $(window).scroll(function () {
   var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
      $('header').fadeOut(500);
   }
   else {
       $('header').fadeIn(500);
   }
   previousScroll = currentScroll;
  });
  }());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried working if want to hide until top scroll try this :

```js
 (function () {
      var previousScroll = 0;

   $(window).scroll(function () {
   var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
      $('#menu-bar').fadeOut(0);
   }
   else {
       $('#menu-bar').fadeIn(0);
   }
  });
  }());
```